# Specifying First Nav ul With jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to use a jQuery plugin called menuFlip ONLY on the first ul for my navigation menu. but for some reason, no matter what I do, it applies menuFlip to all of the sub-menu's too.

This is what I am using to start the plugin:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('ul:first-child').menuFlip();
});
```

This is the actual HTML for the navigation menu:

```
<div id="navigation-menu">
<ul id="flip_nav">
    <li class="main-li"><a href="/home">Home</a></li>
    <li class="main-li"><a href="/page/202624/about" class="dropdown">Community</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
       <li><a href="#">Information</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Rosters</a></li>
      </ul> 
    </li>
    <li class="main-li"><a href="/forums" class="dropdown">Forums</a></li>
    <li class="main-li"><a href="/join" class="dropdown">Join</a></li>
    <li class="main-li"><a href="/generalgamingnews" class="dropdown">Content</a></li>
    <li class="main-li"><a href="/calendar" class="dropdown">Events</a></li>
    <li class="main-li"><a href="teamsg" class="dropdown">Competitive</a></li>
    <li class="main-li"><a href="/livestream">Live Streams</a></li>
    <li class="main-li"><a href="/store">Store</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you have multiple `<ul>` elements with the `flip_nav` id?

Comment: Reproduce your problem with a [live demo](http://jsFiddle.net/).

Comment: Live demo is here: http://www.sentinelgaming.net/testpage

Comment: Yes, where we can't easily examine, or modify, the html, CSS or JavaScript. This is, I was hoping you might have realised, less convenient for us to work with. And reduces the chance of your getting a good answer that solves your problem: help *us* to help *you*. Also, the act of reproducing your problem gives you a debug stage, where you might realise for yourself what the problem(s) is/are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('ul:first-of-type').menuFlip();
});
```

Note that this was only added from jQuery 1.9.

---

EDIT: of course it applies it to the sumenus. They are inside the one you called.

### Solution

I had to make some changes to the plugin itself. I don't understand why the creators of this plugin didn't build it this way from the begin - or at least give you an option to enable/disable children. Anyway, all children were targeted (`find()`), so I had to change some things. Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/e2ST7/2

jQuery

```
/**
 * jQuery menuFlip plugin
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2011 Garrett Grimm (grimmdude.com)
 * Dual licensed under the MIT and GPL licenses:
 * http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
 * http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html
 * Edited by Bram Vanroy for use for one level menu
 *
 */

(function ($) {
    $.fn.menuFlip = function (options) {

        var settings = $.extend({
            'li_height': '20px',
                'flip_speed': 150,
                'flipped_class': 'flipped_item'
        }, options);

        // Set required CSS
        this.children('li').css({
            'overflow': 'hidden',
                'height': settings.li_height
        });

        this.children('li > a').css({
            'display': 'block'
        });

        // For each list item set the child 'a' line height to match the li height and duplicate
        this.children('li').children('a').each(function () {
        // Direct child selector does not seem to be working. Needs review
            $(this)
                .css('line-height', settings.li_height)
                .clone()
                .appendTo($(this).parent())
                .addClass(settings.flipped_class);
        });

        // When list item is hovered slide up to expose the flipped link
        this.children('li').hover(function () {
            var negative_height = '-' + settings.li_height;

            $(this).children('li > a:first').animate({
                marginTop: negative_height
            }, settings.flip_speed);
        },

        function () {
            $(this).children('li > a:first').animate({
                marginTop: '0px'
            }, settings.flip_speed);
        });
    };
})(jQuery);

$('ul#flip-nav').menuFlip();
```

Comment: There must be something obvious i'm missing because even this didn't work. You can view this example here: http://www.sentinelgaming.net/testpage

Comment: So how can we make it only apply to the main menu?

Answer (score 1):

Use :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('ul#flip_nav').menuFlip();
});
```

Comment: This is what I had originally. Unfortunately it still applies it to the others.

Comment: If you only have one element with that ID it shouldn't apply it to the others. But you might be doing something wrong. I executed this on the website you shared and it works. Do you get errors with this?

Comment: Go here: http://www.sentinelgaming.net/testpage and hover over "Community". You will notice that the sub-ul items are also flipping.

Answer (score 1):

Use `$('ul:first')` or `$('ul').first()`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('#flip_nav ul:first').menuFlip();
```

Comment: This was interesting because it disabled the main ul but still had the  nested ul's doing the flip. So i'm not sure how that happened.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing this - ( here http://www.sentinelgaming.net/testpage)

```
$('#flip_nav ul:first').menuFlip();
```

where `#flip_nav` is itself the `ul` which you are wanting to flip, `#flip_nav ul:first` will go inside of your `ul` which you don't want.

Try this  -

```
$('#flip_nav').menuFlip(); // #flip_nav is unique right ?
```

Comment: This is what I had originally. This still applies to all of them for some reason.

Comment: Can you update your `testpage` with what you had `$('#flip_nav').menuFlip();`

Comment: Using that will do exactly what it is doing on the page currently. It will flip all of the main menu items, but also flip the sub-menu items under "Community". Right now, the only things I have is either doing menu flip everywhere, or breaking it completely. No in-between yet.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the plugin is that it applies the effect to all `<li>` and `<a>` inside a parent. An easy fix is to change that in the plugin itself by for example applying a class to `<a>` and ignore that class in the function.

```
<li><a href="#" class='ignore'>Information</a>
```

And part of the menuFlip.js

```
        $(this).find('li').hover(function () {
            var negative_height = '-' + settings.li_height;

            $(this).find('a:first:not(.ignore)').animate({
                marginTop: negative_height
            }, settings.flip_speed);
        },

        function () {
            $(this).find('a:first:not(.ignore)').animate({
                marginTop: '0px'
            }, settings.flip_speed);
        });
```

[See fiddle for changes](http://jsfiddle.net/29KJ3/)